# How to compare two strings ignoring case in Swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, string

How can we compare two strings in swift ignoring case ?
for eg :

```
var a = "Cash"
var b = "cash"
```

Is there any method that will return true if we compare  var a & var b

Comment: You could convert both to lower case before doing comparison.

Comment: Just to note that `lowercaseString` that is mentioned in some answers will fail in some languages (Straße != STRASSE for example)

Comment: @Alladinian how would you suggest doing it then.  Most examples to solve this issue show converting to either all upper case or all lower case?

Comment: @Steve Apple suggests `caseInsensitiveCompare:` & `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` instead

Comment: @Alladinian thank you, do those handle your example as well?

Comment: @Steve Sure! (you can try `"Straße".localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("STRASSE")` - Remember to import `Foundation`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = "Cash"
var b = "cash"
let result: NSComparisonResult = a.compare(b, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)

// You can also ignore last two parameters(thanks 0x7fffffff)
//let result: NSComparisonResult = a.compare(b, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
```

result is type of NSComparisonResult enum:

```
enum NSComparisonResult : Int {

    case OrderedAscending
    case OrderedSame
    case OrderedDescending
}
```

So you can use if statement:

```
if result == .OrderedSame {
    println("equal")
} else {
    println("not equal")
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the range and locale parameters are optional and can be omitted entirely.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wanted to show whole method with all of the parameters.

Comment: You should have the right answer here. Comparing strings is not only about knowing if they are equal or not

Answer (score 204):

Try this :

For older swift:

```
var a : String = "Cash"
var b : String = "cash"

if(a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame){
    println("Et voila")
}
```

---

Swift 3+

```
var a : String = "Cash"
var b : String = "cash"
    
if(a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame){
    print("Et voila")
}
```

Comment: In Swift 3 you need to use `a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame`

Comment: Note: `caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)` is not included in the Swift Standard Library, rather it is part of the `Foundation` framework, thus, requiring `import Foundation`.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is any better than `a.lowercased() == b.lowercased()` ?

Comment: @jowie as mentioned in the other comments, using lower/uppercased() may fail on certain languages.

Comment: `a.localizedStandardRange(of: b) == a.startIndex..<a.endIndex` seems to work better for me and supports localization. The above code doesn’t work for all languages (case rules may differ). Also all `localized*Compare()` return false if `a = "Et voila"` and `b = "Et voilà"`, when it should be true.

Answer (score 42):

Use `caseInsensitiveCompare` method:

```
let a = "Cash"
let b = "cash"
let c = a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame
print(c) // "true"
```

[ComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414769-caseinsensitivecompare) tells you which word comes earlier than the other in lexicographic order (i.e. which one comes closer to the front of a dictionary). `.orderedSame` means the strings would end up in the same spot in the dictionary

Comment: what does `.orderedSame` mean? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/comparisonresult) just say _The two operands are equal_. But why is the word 'order' used here? Is there a sequence or something? And what does _The left operand is smaller than the right operand._ (`.orderedAscending`) mean for strings

Comment: @Honey Comparison result tells you which word comes earlier than the other in lexicographic order (i.e. which one comes closer to the front of a dictionary). `.orderedSame` means the strings would end up in the same spot in the dictionary.

Comment: @Honey `.orderedSame` is short for `ComparisonResult.orderSame` ... you don't have to name the type since the compiler knows that `caseInsensitiveCompare` returns a `ComparisonResult`. "The two operands are equal" -- they are equal according to a specific ordering ... clearly, "Cash" and "cash" are not identical string values. "But why is the word 'order' used here?" -- because it's the result of an ordered comparison. The other values are `orderedAscending` and `orderedDescending` ... it's not just a question of same or different. As for "smaller": strings are like numbers in a large base.

Comment: I feel like this is terrible API design. The signature is not easy to read...Making it `a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b, comparing: .orderedSame)` would have been more readable...

Answer (score 27):

```
if a.lowercaseString == b.lowercaseString {
    //Strings match
}
```

Comment: Pure Swift is the way to go here. No need for foundation.

Comment: Converting case and then comparing is wrong. See the comments under the question.

Comment: @JimBalter I wouldn't say it's "wrong" since it answers the example given in the OP's question. For those of us who don't need to support localization this is much  cleaner!

Comment: ^ No, it's wrong. That something happens to work for one example is irrelevant. This hack is not "cleaner" at all. The accepted answer gives the correct, clean solution.

Answer (score 13):

> **localizedCaseInsensitiveContains** : Returns whether the receiver contains a given string by performing a case-insensitive, locale-aware search

```
if a.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(b) {
    //returns true if a contains b (case insensitive)
}
```

**Edited**:

> **caseInsensitiveCompare** : Returns the result of invoking compare(_:options:) with NSCaseInsensitiveSearch as the only option.

```
if a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame {
    //returns true if a equals b (case insensitive)
}
```

Comment: The question is about comparison, not containment.

Comment: If *"a contains b"* and *"b contains a"*, they are equal. So this is surely a possible solution, even if it may not be the most effective one.

Answer (score 10):

**CORRECT WAY:**

```
let a: String = "Cash"
let b: String = "cash"

if a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame {
    //Strings match 
}
```

***Please note:*** ComparisonResult.orderedSame can also be written as .orderedSame in shorthand.

**OTHER WAYS:**

**a.**

```
if a.lowercased() == b.lowercased() {
    //Strings match 
}
```

**b.**

```
if a.uppercased() == b.uppercased() {
    //Strings match 
}
```

**c.**

```
if a.capitalized() == b.capitalized() {
    //Strings match 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Could just roll your own:

```
func equalIgnoringCase(a:String, b:String) -> Bool {
    return a.lowercaseString == b.lowercaseString
}
```

Comment: Converting case and then comparing is wrong. See the comments under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Phone numbers comparison example; using swift 4.2

```
var selectPhone = [String]()

if selectPhone.index(where: {$0.caseInsensitiveCompare(contactsList[indexPath.row].phone!) == .orderedSame}) != nil {
    print("Same value")
} else {
    print("Not the same")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write your String Extension for comparison in just a few line of code

```
extension String {

    func compare(_ with : String)->Bool{
        return self.caseInsensitiveCompare(with) == .orderedSame
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5 
Ignoring the case and compare two string

```
var a = "cash"
var b = "Cash"
if(a.caseInsensitiveCompare(b) == .orderedSame){
     print("Ok")
}
```

Comment: This duplicates many previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4, I went the String extension route using caseInsensitiveCompare() as a template (but allowing the operand to be an optional). Here's the playground I used to put it together (new to Swift so feedback more than welcome).

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func caseInsensitiveEquals<T>(_ otherString: T?) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol {
        guard let otherString = otherString else {
            return false
        }
        return self.caseInsensitiveCompare(otherString) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame
    }
}

"string 1".caseInsensitiveEquals("string 2") // false

"thingy".caseInsensitiveEquals("thingy") // true

let nilString1: String? = nil
"woohoo".caseInsensitiveEquals(nilString1) // false
```

Comment: You can just use `.orderedSame` rather than `ComparisonResult.orderedSame`.

Answer (score 0):

Created an extension function for it. Pass `caseSensitive` as `false` if you want case insensitive compare.

```swift
extension String {
    
    func equals(to string: String, caseSensitive: Bool = true) -> Bool {
        if caseSensitive {
            return self.compare(string) == .orderedSame
        } else {
            return self.caseInsensitiveCompare(string) == .orderedSame
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```swift
"cash".equals(to: "Cash", caseSensitive: false) //returns true
"cash".equals(to: "Cash") //returns false
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3**: You can define your own operator, e.g. `~=`.

```
infix operator ~=

func ~=(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
   return lhs.caseInsensitiveCompare(rhs) == .orderedSame
}
```

Which you then can try in a playground

```
let low = "hej"
let up = "Hej"

func test() {
    if low ~= up {
        print("same")
    } else {
        print("not same")
    }
}

test() // prints 'same'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but note that this is generally a quite bad idea, since the custom pattern matching operator above will take precedence over the native pattern matching usually used when matching `String` instances to eachother (or to other `String` literals). Imagine `let str = "isCAMELcase"` being switched over, with a case as follows: `case "IsCamelCase": ... `. With the method above, this `case` would be entered successfully, which is not expected coming from the standard libs implementation of `String` pattern matching. An updated Swift 3 answer is still good though, but ...

Comment: ... consider using a custom function (or `String` extension) as helper above rather than overriding the default `String` pattern matching.

Answer (score -2):

You could also make all the letters uppercase (or lowercase) and see if they are the same.

```
var a = “Cash”
var b = “CASh”

if a.uppercaseString == b.uppercaseString{
  //DO SOMETHING
}
```

This will make both variables as `”CASH”` and thus they are equal.

You could also make a `String` extension

```
extension String{
  func equalsIgnoreCase(string:String) -> Bool{
    return self.uppercaseString == string.uppercaseString
  }
}

if "Something ELSE".equalsIgnoreCase("something Else"){
  print("TRUE")
}
```

Comment: Converting case and then comparing is wrong. See the comments under the question.

Answer (score -2):

Swift 3

```
if a.lowercased() == b.lowercased() {

}
```

Comment: This is wrong. See the comments under the question.

Answer (score -3):

Swift 3:

You can also use the localized case insensitive comparison between two strings function and it returns `Bool`

```
var a = "cash"
var b = "Cash"

if a.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(b) {
    print("Identical")           
} else {
    print("Non Identical")
}
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Consider the strings "casha" and "Cash"

Answer (score -3):

```
extension String
{
    func equalIgnoreCase(_ compare:String) -> Bool
    {
        return self.uppercased() == compare.uppercased()
    }
}
```

sample of use

```
print("lala".equalIgnoreCase("LALA"))
print("l4la".equalIgnoreCase("LALA"))
print("laLa".equalIgnoreCase("LALA"))
print("LALa".equalIgnoreCase("LALA"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some strings in some languages ... see the comments under the question, and the many correct answers, some of which -- including the accepted one -- preceded yours by years.