# Non-case-sensitive switch statement in swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm playing around with an app that takes in user input, and prints a simple output.

My code looks like this:

```
switch text {
        case "Hi", "hi", "Hello", "hello", "Good day", "good day":
            return "Hello, sir."
        default:
            return "Sorry, I didn't understand!"
}
```

My question is, instead of having 5-10 possible inputs for one output, is it possible to put one input that isn't case sensitive? For example, could I just put "hello", and have my statement check for "Hello", "hello", "HELLO", etc.?

Comment: `switch text.lowercased()` and type out lowercased-only strings in the different cases of your `switch` statement. Just note that some special characters don't translate as one might expect when applying `lowercased()` or `uppercased()` to them: see [the following Q&A for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532728/how-to-compare-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-swift-language) (specifically the comments to the question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could uppercase `text` (or lowercase [`lowercased()`] as mentioned in the comments), so case would not matter:

```
switch text.uppercased() {
case "HI", "HELLO", "GOOD DAY":
  return "Hello, sir."
default:
  return "Sorry, I didn't understand!"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The most elegant solution would be to use the lesser known `String.CompareOptions` in combination with `.range(of:, options:)`. This allows you to perform much complex operations with less effort, such as **matching ignoring special characters, not only case** and the use of regular expression (which would be of great advantage for your specific purpose). If you don't know what they are, I recommend you look into it.

Back to topic:
You can read more about `String.CompareOptions` [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring.compareoptions). The documentation is for `NSString`, but these are available for `String`, too.

You would then use it as follows:

```
let userInput = "HeLLö, how are you doing? Greetings!"

let acceptedWords = ["hello", "hi", "greeting"]

var resultCommants = acceptedWords.filter { (word) -> Bool in
    return userInput.range(of: word, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil
}

// resultCommands = ["hello", "greeting"]
```

As you can see, `HeLLö` matches `hello` and `Greetings` matches `greeting` because of `.caseInsensitive` and `.diacriticInsensitive`.

If you're not familiar with the `.filter` operator, it iterates through your array and, for each item `word`, expects you to return either true or false, depending on if the item should be included in the filtered version of your array. Here this is done by comparing the result of `.range(of:, options:)` to `nil`. Unequal `nil` means the word was found, equal nil if not. You could of course use the range, if you wanted to know *where* the word was found.

Comment: This approach is good if we want to combine several compare options, but I believe using [`compare(_:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1410893-compare) and testing vs `.orderedSame` has better semantics (in this context) than the `range(...)` test vs non-`nil` (since in this context, we don't actually make use of the range optionally produced by the call to `range(of:options:)`).

Comment: Yes, you're right. It ultimately comes down to the same. The important thing to me is making use of the `options`, specially `.diacriticInsensitive`, which would otherwise be extremely difficult to implement (`.caseInsensitive` is much simpler).

Comment: I wish they implemented `contains(_:options:)` for using the compare options in a simpler, cleaner Bool function.

Comment: You could overload the `contains(_:contains:) -> ComparisonResult` to a `Bool`-returning one, where your own implementation simply calls the prior method and compares the result against `.orderedSame` (to yield the `Bool` return). The overload of your choice will be inferred from context (e.g. your custom one when used as a predicate for `filter`).

Comment: Yes, of course :) But somehow I still find it odd that the method is not overloaded already officially. (It would mean a lot more people making use of the advanced options and hopefully not implementing bad matching logic).

Comment: I agree it could be plausible to have such a method officially, but I believe the API guidelines for naming methods (conventions) would invalidate `compare` as a valid choice in such an overload. A method for testing "equality" (or rather, same ordering) for some give compare options would probably have a name like `isOrderedSame(as:compareOptions:)`, or something along those lines :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution:

```
func check(input: String) -> Bool {
    let strings = ["Hi", "hi", "Hello", "hello", "Good day", "good day"]

    let inputLowercase = input.lowercased()
    return strings.first(where: { $0.lowercased() == inputLowercase }) != nil
}
```

Comment: Note that whenever you find yourself using a statement like `...first(where: ...) != nil`, e.g. looking for some element given some predicate, but _not making use of that element_, you can simply use `contains(where: ...)` instead. E.g., above, `return strings.contains(where: { $0.lowercased() == input.lowercased() })`. Since you are not applying pattern matching, however, the is no reason not to use the existing case-insensitive compare tools already readily available (here, from `Foundation`): e.g. `return strings.contains(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(input) == .orderedSame })`.