# Swift Console input not case sensitive

Tags: swift, macos, if-statement, case-sensitive

i just started learning Swift3. For the beginning i write a console program for converting units. I have a console input stream

```
let typ = readLine()
```

and of cause i get the exact same string back but i use this in a if statement. Now my Problem i don't want to check it case sensitive i only want the plain string. 
This is the if construct i use:

```
if typ == unitA {
    print("foo")
    //Some Code
}else if typ == unitB{
    print("super foo")
    //Some Code
}else{
    print("Invalid input :/")
}
```

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply lowercase the input before comparing it. Also, a `switch` statement can greatly clean up the `if`/`if else`/`else` ladder.

```
guard let input = readLine() else {
    fatalError("No input recieved")
}

switch input.lowercased() {
    case unitA: print("foo")
    case unitB: print("super foo")
    default: print("Invalid input :/")
}
```

Comment: But can you explain this sniped to me? 
`guard let input = readLine() else {
    fatalError("No input recieved")
}
 `

Comment: @Limatuz What ?

Comment: @Limatuz https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the string based case insensitive you can use `caseInsensitiveCompare` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533007/3729825)