# Case incensitive filter searchable text in an array of strings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an array of strings within a struct. This populates a list, and I use a .searchable to filter elements there. I can filter them by text, date, or tags within each item. All done without regard for the case.

Now, for the tags, I'm struggling to find the right way to filter them:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

struct LibItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var date = Date()
    var dateText: String {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d yyyy, h:mm a"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    var tags: [String] = []
}

final class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("myapp") public var collectables: [LibItem] = []

    init() {
        self.collectables = self.collectables.sorted(by: {
            $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
        })
    }

    func sortList() {
        self.collectables = self.collectables.sorted(by: {
            $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
        })
    }    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
    @State var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(filteredItems) { collectable in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(collectable.text).font(.body).padding(.leading).padding(.bottom, 1)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .searchable(
                text: $searchText,
                placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
                prompt: "Search..."
            )
        } 
    }

    var filteredItems: [LibItem] {       
        switch selectedItem {
        case 1: // date
            return data.collectables.filter {
                searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.dateText.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        case 2: //tags <--- here how do I search and filter by, case insensitive?
            return data.collectables.filter {
                searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.tags.contains(searchText)
            }
        default:
            return data.collectables.filter {
                searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For strict equality, case insensitive:

```
return data.collectables.filter {
   searchText.isEmpty
      ? true
      : $0.tags.contains { tag in tag.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchText) == .orderedSame }
}
```

for substrings, you can use the `range(of:)` method:

```
return data.collectables.filter {
   searchText.isEmpty
      ? true
      : $0.tags.contains { tag in tag.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
}
```

or, use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` which you have already used before:

```
return data.collectables.filter {
   searchText.isEmpty
      ? true
      : $0.tags.contains { tag in tag.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
}
```

Comment: `range(of:)` worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Compare two lowercased strings, by momentarily turning both sides of the comparison lowercased.

An example you can use in your code:

```
$0.tags.compactMap { $0.lowercased() }.contains(searchText.lowercased())
```

If you need to check whether each single item of `tags` contains *part* of the string, you need to iterate:

```
var isTagFound = false
$0.tags.compactMap { $0.lowercased() }.forEach {
    if $0.contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
        isTagFound = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works if the search term is *exactly* the tag. Any way to match any part of the word? I like I did with the text and dates?

Comment: @Aleph: just edited the reply.

Comment: @Aleph don't use this kind of approach when doing a case insensitive comparison. It might return the wrong result depending on the language/locale. Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532728/how-to-compare-two-strings-ignoring-case-in-swift-language#comment49139402_30532728)